# Plugins issues in Netbeans 6.9

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I used to work with the (nice) Javascript and Jquery plugins in Netbeans 6.8. But after the update, I've lost all my plugins (actually, I've lost all my settings too, nice job guys ...) and I'm unable to find the JS plugins again, even after checking all the sources, nor can I find the package on the net. Any idea ?

Extra question :  How can I change the font in **menus** (not the code's font) ? Default font really hurts the retina.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but about the "font" question, try this:
**http://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/themes/themes.html**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the plugins you have used to work with are still not ported to 6.9 - you could try to find the plugins here: http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/updates and try to install them manually.